# Rails Active Admin change url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I want to change the url to make it singular.
Is there a way to change the "/admin/names/" to "/admin/name/"?

I have tried going through the documentation on http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html and https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/tree/master/docs but i have not been able to find anything.

Comment: if you declare your method as `name` instead of `names` it will do the rest

Comment: @RajarshiDas name is a resource name, hence it will be always declared singular, but in url it is displayed plural.

Comment: ok if you want custom routes on active admin you can simply do `match "/admin/name" => 'admin/users#names', via: :get, as: "admin_name"`

Comment: if you declare actions `ActiveAdmin.register Users do
    actions :name  collection_action :name do ... end
end`

Comment: Accepted it now, just forgot it

Comment: @user3803797 no problems, I was just wondering if that worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your need makes no sense, but still..

In order to achieve it you would want to define the route manually.

Add following lines under `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)` in `routes.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
get 'admin/name', to: 'admin/names#index'
```